# Google Earth plugin not working in Awesomium

Tags: c#

We used Awesomium's demo browser to open this page:
http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/earth/

The problem is that the Google Earth window is completely off of its position, in the top-left hand corner, as you can see here:
https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Public/Problem.png?w=017bd4f4

The same thing happens with the Awesomium WebComponent under Visual Studio.

Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks in advance

System: Windows 7 x64.

Comment: I don't see a programming issue here. It sounds like Awesomium may have some bugs. Do you have code that you believe contains an error?

Comment: Your image seems to be a broken link already. Can you reupload it using the imgur upload tool in the post editor? Thanks.